# Get Multiple Files From Blob Storage With Azure Function Bindings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to get multiple files from azure function bindings without knowing the file or folder names in advance?
For a different function I have this:

```
 public async Task<Activity> GetActivity([ActivityTrigger] Activity activity,
     [Blob("activities/migration/{activity.Id}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream activityBlob,
     ILogger log)
 {

 }
```

And this will get the file from the migration folder based on the id within activity class.

But for another function there will be a large amount of files some within folders, the ids will not be known in advance. So this cannot be passed as a parameter to access the blob.

My questions is, is there a 'get all' or 'get recursively' for these bindings?
Something that will get all files and folders within a container?

If not through bindings perhaps through code?

Comment: I don't think so. Each new/modified blob will generate an event, and this one is what actually triggers your function.

Comment: absolutely, you can bind to the container https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8p8RmOg9iw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible through a blob input binding ,but you can use a dynamic input binding to get all the files from a container.please refer below code:-

```
public async Task<Activity> Run(
            [ActivityTrigger] Activity activity,
            IBinder binder,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var blobs= await binder.BindAsync<IEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob>>(new BlobAttribute(blobPath: $"activities/migration")
            {
                Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            });
            
        }
```

This will give you a list of all blobs in a container then probably you can proceed further with your operations ,Another way would be to use the **ListBlobsSegmentedAsync** method on a container reference in the code.