# How to get Multiple FIlename from blobtrigger azure function c#

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

How to get Multiple Filename from container using blobtrigger azure function c#?

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194719/get-multiple-files-from-blob-storage-with-azure-function-bindings) answers your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

**`Sample:`**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace FunctionApp116
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "str")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob,ILogger log)
        {
            string blobname = myBlob.Name;
            string containername = myBlob.Container.Name;
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("str"));
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containername);
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{blobname}" + $" Container Name is {containername}");
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs())
            {
                log.LogInformation("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Original Answer:**

The blob that blob trigger can input can not be more than one.

But, you can use blob storage sdk to get multiple blobs from the same container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#code-examples

if you offer what language you are using, i can post a sample.